# How to count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string?

Tags: php, string, substring

Anybody can tell me about  how to find the number of occurrence  of substring in the given string without using the string function  . for example the string is "**when the men get the hen**"  and the result i expected is the substring '**he**' occur **4** times in the given string.

Comment: preg_match_all would be a quick guess

Comment: What do you mean by “without using the string function during the run time”?

Comment: well after C, you move to php :D

Answer (score 21):

```
substr_count('when the men get the hen', 'he');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: that mean with out using any string function to bring the result

Answer (score 6):

Without using any string functions?

Is there any real point in restricting yourself to a set of functions that excludes those specially designed to do what you're trying to do?

```
$string = 'when the men get the hen';
$substring = 'he';

$cArr = explode($substring,$string);
$substring_count = count($cArr) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Step through the string one character at a time

Check if the current character is an 'h'

If it is check if the next character is an 'e'

If it is an 'e', increase your counter by 1

Go back to step 1