# Extracting a substring from a string of random letters

Tags: php, string

I have string that is random in nature example 'CBLBTTCCBB'. My goal is to count the occurrence of the string `CTLBT` in the string `CBLBTTCCBB`. Repetition of letters used for checking is not allowed. For example, once `CTLBT` is formed, the remaining random letters for the next iteration will be `BCCB`.

The scenario is that we have scratch card where users can win letters to form the word `CTLBT`. Based on the records of the user the letters that he won are in a string `CBLBTTCCBB` that is ordered from left to right based on the purchase of the scratch card.

I thought of using `strpos` but it seems inappropriate since it uses the exact arrangement of the substring from larger string.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Note:
Question is not a duplicate of [How to count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118303/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string) since the solution posted in the given link is different.  `substr_count` counts the occurrence of a substring from a string that assumes the string is in a correct order in which the substring will be formed.

Comment: Did you try http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php ?

Comment: @DevDonkey So far I'm still gathering my thoughts on the matter. I thought of looping the whole string but I guess it will be inefficient.

Comment: @VladimirGilevich Tried substr_count but It does not take into account the randomness of the haystack. My goal is to get the occurrence of the target string that is formed from the random string.

Comment: @Jhn So you want to check how many times  `CTLBT` occurs  in every order combination of `CBLBTTCCBB` ?

Comment: @Jhn Hm, can you give real example with real problem? Because from current example it looks like substr_count() is best solution...

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Rizier123  Updated question

Comment: @VladimirGilevich Added more context to my scenario.

Comment: @Jhn Now do you want to count how many times the substring occurs in all order combinations, or just in which order the substring occurs the most?

Comment: @Rizier123 Updated question to for the constraint of the checker.

Comment: @Jhn So - it looks like you need test if all characters from string `CTLBT` present in `CBLBTTCCBB`? right? it is not important to have exact combination `CTLBT` in string `CBLBTTCCBB`?

Comment: @VladimirGilevich Yes.

Comment: @Jhn Added one more variant in answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly I would do this (with prints for showing the results):

```
<?
# The string to test
$string="CBLBTTCCBBTLTCC";
# The winning word
$word="CTLBT";

# Get the letters from the word to use them as unique array keys
$letters=array_unique(str_split($word));
print("Letters needed are:\n".print_r($letters,1)."\n");

# Initialize the work array
$match=array("count" => array(),"length"=> array());
# Iterate over the keys to build the array with the number of time the letter is occuring
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
  $match['length'][$letter] = substr_count($word,$letter); #Number of time this letter appears in the winning word
  $match['count'][$letter] = floor(substr_count($string,$letter) / $match['length'][$letter]); # count the letter (will be 0 if none present) and divide by the number of time it should appear, floor it so we have integer

}
print("Count of each letter divided by their appearance times:\n".print_r($match['count'],1)."\n");

# Get the minimum of all letter to know the number of times we can make the winning word
$wins = min($match['count']);
# And print the result
print("Wins: $wins\n");
?>
```

wich output:

```
Letters needed are:
Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => T
    [2] => L
    [3] => B
)

Count of each letter divided by their appearance times:
Array
(
    [C] => 5
    [T] => 2
    [L] => 2
    [B] => 4
)

Wins: 2
```

As you wish to count the combination regardless of the order, the minimum count of letter will be the number of times the user win, if one letter is not present, it will be 0.

I let you transform this into a function and clean the print lines you don't wish ;)

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai! I will try to implement the one that you suggested as the better option

Comment: @jhn let me know, I was short in time right now, I will have more time to improve it later in the day

Comment: @Jhn Answer improved, let me know if there's something unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Probably then instead strpos you can use preg_replace then:

```
function rand_substr_count($haystack, $needle)
{
    $result = $haystack;

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($needle); $i++) {
        $result = preg_replace('/'.$needle[$i].'/', '', $result, 1);
    }

    if (strlen($haystack) - strlen($result) == strlen($needle)) {
        return 1 + rand_substr_count($result, $needle);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

echo rand_substr_count("CBLBTTCCBB", "CTLBT");
```

Comment: OP wish to know how many times the search is present (if someone won twice or more times)

Comment: @Tensibai thanks for note! - moved code to function - now it is easy to use to get count.

Comment: Nice use of recursive function :) May I ask why `preg_replace` and not `str_replace` for the single letter replace ? (IIRC it's faster, but I may be wrong)

Comment: `str_replace()` will replace all present characters, but with `preg_replace()` we can replace only first found character. So - just for this nuance `preg_replace()` is better here.

Comment: Aww, indeed, read the doc again and saw I forgot the $count in str_replace is a placeholder and not a limit. Sorry ;)